# Preventing inverse friendships from being created via has_many through type of relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a facebook clone for a project, and I'm having trouble preventing friendships from being created for relationships that already technically exist.

For example, person A sends a friend request to person B, who accepts. This created a record where person A = "user_id", and person B = "friend_id". Person A is prevented from sending another friend request to person B on a database level with this line:

```
t.index ["user_id", "friend_id"], name: "index_friendships_on_user_id_and_friend_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

However, person B can still send a request to person A no problem. I tried to prevent this with the reverse of the line above:

```
t.index ["friend_id", "user_id"], name: "index_friendships_on_friend_id_and_user_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

I now realize that this still allows one reverse friendship to be created, but no more DUPLICATE reverse relationships....

So, I suppose I need to write a custom callback (forgive me if I'm throughout around incorrect terms) that will check the DB for duplicate friendships before saving the record, correct?

Comment: A custom callback could face race conditions. I'd recommend simply hiding the invite functionality from the UI if the friendship exists between two users.

Comment: I can do that, but that's good enough? What if it were something more important and damaging, where if a user really wanted to they could manually create duplicate records via a console or something?

Comment: If you're worried about shenanigans, you could add a `before_action` to your controller that returns an error or fails silently.